# how to apply all class names values ? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selectors-api

I'm trying to add a text below an img button that when the user hovers over it (`mouseover`) it will show a text under the image.

When I'm testing this code:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("img")
var i;
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        console.log("boom!");
    }, false);
}
```

Everytime im over any of the images the console.log will work but when im trying this:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("img")
var i;
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        document.querySelector(".done-text").innerHTML = "MAKE IT DONE!"
    }, false);
}
```

Only the first img button will display the text.
It's a row of image buttons with the same class.

I've tried `selectorAll` but it keeps showing errors on the console.
Thanks for helping.

Adam.

HTML:

```
<img src="images/com.png" height="30px"><p class="done-text"><p></td>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML to go with this please. Seeing the structure of your HTML might help offer a solution.

Comment: `querySelector` only returns one element.  `querySelectorAll` can return multiple

Comment: i've added the html code

Comment: There's not a single img tag in your html

Comment: Please edit the HTML to display only the relevant parts to your question. I can see you will have multiple `<img src="images/com.png" height="30px"></a><p class="done-text"><p>` showing in a table.

Comment: scroll to the right you will see - <img src="images/com.png" height="30px"></a><p class="done-text"><p></td>

Comment: Have you thought about using the title attribute on the image element?

Comment: for what use ??

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet - @luisenrike change to

```
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("img")
    var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
x[i].doneText = document.querySelectorAll(".done-text")[i];
x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
     this.doneText.innerHTML  = "MAKE IT DONE!"
    }, false);
  })(i);
}
```

Sorry if the formatting is bad - mobile doesn't show preview. :-)

Luisenrike's solution was good but didn't account for context within the event listener - it doesn't know the definition of i when called.  If you set a custom property before setting the listener, then you can set innerHTML of that inside the listener with "this".

Answer (score 0):

What about: `document.querySelectorAll(".done-text")[i].innerHTML = "MAKE IT DONE!"`?

Here is an example:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("img")
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".done-text")[i].innerHTML = "MAKE IT DONE!"
    }, false);
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<img src="images/com.png" height="30px" />
<p class="done-text"></p>
<img src="images/com.png" height="30px" />
<p class="done-text"></p>
<img src="images/com.png" height="30px" />
<p class="done-text"></p>
```

Comment: But this would require another loop within the mouseover event right? As your solution suggest will give the following error `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`  https://jsfiddle.net/hz0mo6a0/

Comment: Not really, it depends on what you want to do, I added a complete example

Comment: Well your original answer suggested one minor change. Your update now includes other changes which results in a working solution. You can't assume others will know how to make a minor change work without explaining the reason for the change. Now your answer is good :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `document.querySelector(".done-text")` return an HTMLCollection which does not have a property `.innerHTML`

It is each of the elements in that collection that have the `.innerHTML` property.

What you are trying to do is this:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("img")
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".done-text");
    for (var k = 0; k < elements.length; k++) {
      elements[k].innerHTML = "MAKE IT DONE!";
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is using nextElementSibling, this will need only one loop and only one selection of elements:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'triggered';
  });
})
```

```html
<td><img src="images/com.png" height="30px">
  <p class="done-text"></p>
</td>
<td><img src="images/com.png" height="30px">
  <p class="done-text"></p>
</td>
<td><img src="images/com.png" height="30px">
  <p class="done-text"></p>
</td>
<td><img src="images/com.png" height="30px">
  <p class="done-text"></p>
</td>
<td><img src="images/com.png" height="30px">
  <p class="done-text"></p>
</td>
<td><img src="images/com.png" height="30px">
  <p class="done-text"></p>
</td>
```